# DensityPlot3D produces complex numbers

Tags: plotting, regions

This invocation of `DensityPlot3D[]` is unhappy:

```
DensityPlot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[0 <= z <= Sqrt[1-x^2-y^2], {x, y, z}]]
```

producing lots of complex numbers and divisions by zero. Even using a larger lower bound (on z) of 2^-2 did not do the trick.

OTOH, using a *non*-exact lower bound, say, 0.001, did not cause problems (although gave me an unbalanced plot). (This is exactly the *opposite* behavior of my previous question, where `RegionBounds[]` *insisted* on exact numbers. Sigh.)

Note that there were no such problems with `DensityPlot[]` (i.e., in 2D).

Any explanation?

Thank you.

Comment: I would just avoid region specifications with radicals whenever I can: `RegionEqual[ImplicitRegion[0 <= z <= Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, y, z}], ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]]`.

Comment: Okay, thanx, I will keep that in mind. Although in general, for the many cases I present to my students (in an automated fashion), I do not know if this will always be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Sqrt[ ] is a tricky function. Since you want real values, try using Surd (which gives real-valued roots). Hence

```
DensityPlot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
              ImplicitRegion[0 <= z <= Surd[1 - x^2 - y^2, 2], {x, y, z}]]
```

does not throw any errors.

Comment: Thank you. I should have recalled this, as I have encountered this wall before.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Explicitly specify the constraints on `x` and `y`. Either,

```
DensityPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= z <= Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2] && Sqrt[x^2] < 1 && 
    Sqrt[y^2] < Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y, z}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

or

```
DensityPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2, {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= z <= Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2] && Sqrt[y^2] < 1 && 
    Sqrt[x^2] < Sqrt[1 - y^2], {x, y, z}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although, as I answered J.M., in general, for the many cases I present to my students (in an automated fashion), I do not know if this will always be possible.